# Getting the fill color or any other property of a item drawn in a canvas in tkinter(Python)

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I want to get the fill color or any other property of a item drawn in a canvas
in tkinter.

```
  def createWidgets(self):
    self.canvas_1= tk.Canvas(self, bg='#FAFAFA',selectforeground='#BBDEFB');
    i=self.canvas_1.create_rectangle((self.canvas_1.winfo_reqwidth()/2)+100,
                                   (self.canvas_1.winfo_reqheight()/2)+50,
                                   (self.canvas_1.winfo_reqwidth()/2)+150,
                                   (self.canvas_1.winfo_reqheight()/2)+100, 
                                    fill='#FF4081',width=0)
    self.canvas_1.grid();
    color=               #want to access the fill color of item i using some getter functions.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this using the `itemcget` method:
[effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemcget-method)

so you could use:

```
color = self.canvas_1.itemcget(i, "fill")
```

Comment: is there a setter function like this too if that's not too much to ask, i am making something right now so i need a setter function too

Comment: i got the setter function

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example on how to get the fill color of the rectangle...

```
import Tkinter as Tk

def main(args):
    tk = Tk.Tk()
    canvas_1 = Tk.Canvas(bg='#FAFAFA', selectforeground='#BBDEFB');
    i = canvas_1.create_rectangle((canvas_1.winfo_reqwidth()/2)+100,
                                  (canvas_1.winfo_reqheight()/2)+50,
                                  (canvas_1.winfo_reqwidth()/2)+150,
                                  (canvas_1.winfo_reqheight()/2)+100, 
                                  fill = '#FF4081', width = 0)
    canvas_1.grid();
    #color =
    print(canvas_1.itemcget(i, "fill"))
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```